# unzip a zip file from the server into a android app for offline use - Android App Development

Tags: android, json, android-intent, getjson, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm developing an android application. Currently I've implemented the reading of the JSON file from the server (JSON parsing). Now I'm trying to implement it in offline.

I have a zip file on server contains a JSON file and some images related to that JSON. Now I want to download the zip file and unzip it in a sd card or some other location within the android phone. and then read the JSON file and images from that location. This process has to be done in the background if the user pressed the 'update' button or list item.

I googled for this issue but I couldn't find any appropriate answer. Please help me to solve this matter. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Gson` library for Json serialization/deserialization and `java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream` / `GZIPInputStream` for zipping/unzipping.

If you want the process to occur in the background, you can use a `Service` or specifically an `IntentService`.

If you want to write a file to the sd card, here are some tips as to writing your own files to the sd card: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18167342/326370